# Why are shared headers disabled in Apollo Sandbox?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

`@apollo/server: 4.3.3`

For some reason, when launching Apollo Sandbox on my Staging environment, the "shared headers" feature is disabled.
When I run it locally, the feature is enabled and works fine.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I believe the problem in sandbox UI. You could manually remove disable attribute and it will works.

Comment: @LiashenkoV Thanks for the reply! What do you mean by "manually remove disable attribute"?

Comment: @MaterialZ He means removing the disabled attribute from DOM.
There is a github issue regarding this: https://github.com/apollographql/embeddable-explorer/issues/251